# Hide a part of a graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

How to hide a part of a torus. I mean in the following torus

> ParametricPlot3D[{ (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], (3+ Cos[v]) Cos[u], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

I want to hide the shaded part [image]

Comment: Try `{u, -Pi/8, Pi/8}`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to change the `u` range as suggested by Rohit in comments.

A few additional methods:

Using [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
  Sin[v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> (-Pi + Pi/16 <= #4 <= Pi - Pi/16 &)]
```

[image]

Using [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
  Sin[v]}, {u, -Pi, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{-Pi + Pi/16, Pi - Pi/16}}, 
 MeshShading -> { Automatic,Opacity[.1], Automatic}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can I also remove the frame box and the axes? I mean I only need the torus!

Comment: I actually got another question here. I would like to have the wrapping line (ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t](3 + Cos[t]), Sin[Sqrt[2] t] ( 3+Cos[t]),Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 50}}) only on the shown part of the torus above. Can I do that? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AbdelRahmanAl-Amrat, can think of a quick answer b/c the scales are not the same.

Comment: I have tried to modify the picture based on your answer to this question. I am sorry, I thought the idea of doing things in Mathematica is the same always. I asked a new question about animation again including the situation above. If you can help me in answering this new question that would be very great.. Thank you so much!  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200699/edit-a-code-to-become-with-combined-animations